# how to add value in two columns

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

i'm just learned how to make database here. So i have a project to make database for item inventory and i'm using phpmyadmin. I'm struggling to add values in two columns.

So i have this table:

```
quantity jumlah_masuk  jumlah_keluar  saldo_akhir
-------  ------------  ------------   -----------
 100          50           25            125
```

i want value in column "quantity" is add by value in column "jumlah_masuk" and minus by value in column "jumlah_keluar" then the result will be in column "saldo_akhir"

i'm really dont know what i'm doing here, hopefully anyone can help me with my problem. Every single answer will be appriciated it. Thank you

Comment: Do you want a query with formula? If you're familiar with Excel formula, you can use most of it in MySQL query. It's just that some of the function name might be slightly different. For example in Excel, length is `LEN` however in MySQL its full `LENGTH`.

Comment: Do you want to perform INSERT operation or SELECT operation?

Comment: i want to perform with SELECT operation @PinalPatel

Comment: Ok, then you can use SELECT query from my answer. I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not used to phpmyadmin as well.But from my reading can conclude `MySQL = phpmyadmin.` Please try below and let me know the outcome.

```
SELECT quantity,
       jumlah_masuk,
       jumlah_keluar,
       (quantity+jumlah_masuk)-jumlah_keluar AS saldo_akhir 
      from 'your_database_name_here'
```

Regards

Comment: `MySQL` provides a database, `phpmyadmin` is a management tool for that database. There exist several database management tools and  `phpmyadmin` is not required to use the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query to insert data:

```
INSERT INTO test_table(
  quantity,
  jumlah_masuk,
  jumlah_keluar,
  saldo_akhir)
VALUES (100,50,25,((100+50)-25));
```

You can use the following query to retrive data:
`Note: the following query gives you perfect result if you want to use calculation on only SELECT statement`

```
SELECT
  quantity,
  jumlah_masuk,
  jumlah_keluar,
  ((quantity+jumlah_masuk)-jumlah_keluar) AS saldo_akhir
FROM
  test_table;
```